# Pandas 'groupby' dataframe, how to filter if 'item1 AND 'item2' are in the same group?

Tags: string, filter, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `df` as follows:

| gene | cell type | pathway |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | T-cell | apoptosis |
| CD | T-cell | apoptosis |
| EF | B-cell | apoptosis |
| K | B-cell | Nfkb-path |
| G | B-cell | Nfkb-path |
| E | B-cell | Wnt-path |
| F | B-cell | Wnt-path |
| H | T-cell | Wnt-path |
| I | T-cell | Wnt-path |

I grouped by the 'pathway' column:

```
group_by_pathway = df.groupby('pathway')
```

Now, for each group I want to filter and get all data if:

there is at least one "T-cell" **AND** at least one "B-cell" in the column "cell type", i.e. in this example I want to get

| gene | cell type | pathway |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | T-cell | apoptosis |
| CD | T-cell | apoptosis |
| EF | B-cell | apoptosis |
| E | B-cell | Wnt-path |
| F | B-cell | Wnt-path |
| H | T-cell | Wnt-path |
| I | T-cell | Wnt-path |

and I want to filter out

| gene | cell type | pathway |
| --- | --- | --- |
| K | B-cell | Nfkb-path |
| G | B-cell | Nfkb-path |

I know I can't use `str.contains('item1') & str.contains('item2')` in `DataFrameGroupBy` objects:

> unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'DataFrameGroupBy' and
> 'DataFrameGroupBy

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the groups, and pick out the relevant groups -

```
pathway_grouped = df.groupby('pathway')
relevant_pathways = []
for key, group in pathway_grouped:
    if group['cell type'].str.contains('T-cell').any() and group['cell type'].str.contains('B-cell').any():
        relevant_pathways.append(key)
relevant_pathways
print(df[df['pathway'].isin(relevant_pathways)])

#   gene cell type    pathway
   # 0   AB    T-cell  apoptosis
   # 1   CD    T-cell  apoptosis
   # 2   EF    B-cell  apoptosis
   # 5    E    B-cell   Wnt-path
   # 6    F    B-cell   Wnt-path
   # 7    H    T-cell   Wnt-path
   # 8    I    T-cell   Wnt-path
```